# Terraform referencing(getting) subnet_id not in current definition file

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I am having trouble understanding how to reference a subnet that is not defined in the "current" definition file.

I have two distinct definition files, one for network definition (file A) and other for computing resources (file B).

**How can i reference the subnet defined at file A in file B?**

**File A** contains the following

```
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "NetResourceGroup" {
      name     = "NetworkResources"
      location = "westeurope"
    }

    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
      name                = "mainvnet"
      location            =     "${azurerm_resource_group.NetResourceGroup.location}"
      address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.NetResourceGroup.name}"
    }

    resource "azurerm_subnet" "dcsubnet" {
      name                 = "dcsubnet"
      virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
      resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.NetResourceGroup.name}"
      address_prefix       = "10.0.1.0/24"
    }

    resource "azurerm_subnet" "sqlsubnet" {
      name                 = "sqlsubnet"
      virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
      resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.NetResourceGroup.name}"
      address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
    }
```

**File B** contains the following:

```
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "DCResourceGroup" {
      name     = "DomainControllerVMs"
      location = "westeurope"
    }

    resource "azurerm_storage_account" "DCStorageAccoount" {
      name                     = "domaincontrollersdisks"
      location                 = "${azurerm_resource_group.DCResourceGroup.location}"
      resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.DCResourceGroup.name}"
      account_tier             = "Standard"
      account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_availability_set" "DCAvailabilitySet" {
      name                         = "dcsavailset"
      location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.DCResourceGroup.location}"
      resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.DCResourceGroup.name}"
      platform_fault_domain_count  = 2
      platform_update_domain_count = 2
      managed                      = true
    }

    resource "azurerm_network_interface" "dc1nic" {
      name                = "dcnic${count.index}"
      location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.DCResourceGroup.location}"
      resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.DCResourceGroup.name}"

      ip_configuration {
        name                                    = "ipconfig${count.index}"
        subnet_id                               = "${?????????}"
        private_ip_address_allocation           = "Dynamic"
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance